# Textbook Wave Example Clarification

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

My textbook gives the following wave example:

> $$\psi(y, t) = (0.040)\sin\left[ 2 \pi \left( \dfrac{y}{6.0 \times 10^{-7}} + \dfrac{t}{2.0 \times 10^{-15}} \right) \right]$$

It then claims that (1) the wave travels in the negative $y$ direction and (2) the speed $v = \nu \lambda = (5.0 \times 10^{14} Hz)(6.0 \times 10^{-7} m) = 3.0 \times 10^8 m/s$.

I know that the equation of a progressive wave travelling in the positive $x$ direction is $\psi(x, t) = A\sin[k(x - vt)]$. So I rearrange to get $\psi(y, t) = (0.040)\sin\left[ \dfrac{2 \pi}{6.0 \times 10^{-7}} \left( y + \dfrac{t (6.0 \times 10^{-7})}{2.0 \times 10^{-15}} \right) \right]$. This gives us the progressive wave equation of the form $\psi(y, t) = A\sin[k(y + vt)]$. With regards to (1), why is this travelling in the *negative* $y$ direction? It seems to me that $y + vt$ is a movement in the *positive* $y$ direction, no? With regards to (2), since we have $y + \dfrac{t (6.0 \times 10^{-7})}{2.0 \times 10^{-15}}$, it seems to me that we have speed $v = \dfrac{6.0 \times 10^{-7}m}{2.0 \times 10^{-15}s} = 3.0 \times 10^8 m/s$, since the numerator is wavelength ($m$) and the denominator is temporal frequency ($s$), right?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Your equation has a positive coefficient for t.  Your pattern equation has a negative coefficient which is for a positive v, Your equation must be for a negative v, which is why the wave travels in the negative direction.

Comment: @BillWatts $y + vt$ is in the positive $y$-direction, is it not? And $x - vt$ is in the positive $x$-direction.

Comment: $y-vt$ is in the positive y direction just like $x-vt$ is in the positive x direction.

Comment: @BillWatts Yes, I seem to have confused myself with the notation. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider what we mean when we say the wave velocity is positive:

[image: Phase velocity]

In my diagram the wave is moving to the right (i.e. in the positive $x$ direction). This means if we consider any point on the wave like the one I have marked with an arrow this point moves right.

The wave equation is:

$$ \psi(t,x) = A \sin(\omega t - kx) $$

which we can write as:

$$ \psi = A \sin(\theta) $$

where $\theta = \omega t - kx$ and we call $\theta$ the *phase*. The point I've marked is where $\theta=0$ so $\psi = \sin(0) = 0$. So when we say the wave moves right we mean the point where $\theta=0$ moves right. And $\theta$ is given by:

$$ \theta = \omega t - kx $$

So if $\theta$ is zero we get:

$$ \omega t - kx = 0 $$

or:

$$ x = \frac{\omega}{k} t $$

And this is just the equation $x = vt$ for an object moving with velocity $v$ with the velocity equal to:

$$ v = \frac{\omega}{k} $$

This is why the equation with $-kx$ describes a wave moving to positive $x$ or conversely if you put $+kx$ you get a wave with negative velocity i.e. moving to negative $x$.

The velocity defined this way is the [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) i.e. it is the velocity that a point of constant phase moves. There is another way to define the velocity called the [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity), though for waves where the velocity is constant the two definitions are the same.

Comment: But how does this relate to my case?

Comment: @ThePointer it explains why a $-kx$ in the equation means a positive velocity. Isn't that what you were asking?

Comment: I was asking why it is that the wave $\psi(y, t) = A\sin[k(y + vt)]$ (the one given in the textbook example) travels in the negative $y$ direction. Because it seems to me that $y + vt$ would be in the positive $y$-direction, no? And $x - vt$ is in the positive $x$-direction.

Comment: @ThePointer yes, the velocity is $-v$ where in this case $v$ is a positive number (the magnitude of the velocity) so it's a negative velocity. I agree it's often confusing whether quantities like $v$ are intended to be vectors or just the magnitude of a vector. Experienced physicists tend to be careless about this since it's obvious to us.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.